# Why ulimit -n value is different in VSCode terminal

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ulimit

I want to check the max value of file descriptor with `ulimit`. But values of ulimit changes among different terminals. Why ulimit values change?

+) Is there any way to check the max value of file descriptor?

[`ulimit -Sa` in iterm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Q9n.png)

[image]

[`ulimit -Sa` in visual studio code terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adSLj.png)

[image]

Comment: Because it can be changed on a per-shell basis. Off topic.

Comment: According to VSCode Github readme https://github.com/microsoft/vscode, it appears OK to post VSCode questions here. eubin, if your question gets closed, you should tweet https://twitter.com/code and see if you get a reply from them. VSC terminal may be setting ulimit -n to that number. Notice that VSC code sets a ulimit in one of their shell scripts: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/scripts/node-electron.sh